# Winforms - If i "Hide()" form "A" from itself, how do i Show() Form A from Form "B"?

Tags: winforms, hide

Windows App -

If i "Hide()" form "A" from itself, how do i Show() Form A from Form "B" without creating another object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just call Show on the existing form instance.  Calling Show does not instantiate the form.

Answer (score -1):

Make the constructor for FormA as private. Create a static Instance. SingleTon. Accessing the form thru the static property will not create the new instances.

Comment: Singletons are way overused.  This is not a situation where you need one -- and if you don't absolutely need one, you shouldn't use one.